# How can I disable headsup notification from FCM and only work with onMessage and onBackgroundMessageHanlder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I disable headsup notification from FCM and only work with

```
  onMessage()
```

and

```
  onBackgroundMessageHanlder()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic notification shows up because you're sending a notification message. For notification messages, FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app.

**Solution:**

You can send a data message which does not display an automatic notification and requires the client app to process the data.

Here's a sample notification message:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample data message:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

More reading: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options